# Why AngularDart don't use rxDart like typescript version?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I am playing with AngularDart and I don't see any reference to rxDart.

Why don't it use rxDart? Why typescript version uses RxJS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AngularDart didn't need it. They got what they needed from Streams in dart.

The Typescript/Dart versions of Angular are pretty disparate at this point. I wouldn't expect if one has something the other will have it too.